# Extract amplitude at beat timestamps using librosa

Tags: python, librosa

I have an audio file (.wav) and I have the beats annotated for that audio.

Eg.

`beats_timestamps = [1.22,2.22,3.33,4.44,5.55]` # dummy example

these values refer to the time(in seconds) where the beats are present in the song/audio.

Also,
I have loaded the audio file using

`audio_signal, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None, duration=60)` # 60 seconds of audio.

My requirement is to extract the amplitude/signal strength at those beats_timestamps..

for that I am currently using

```
beats_to_samples = librosa.time_to_samples(beats, sr=sample_rate)
beat_samples_to_frames = librosa.samples_to_frames(beats_to_samples )
signal_strength_at_beats_timestamps = audio_signal[beat_samples_to_frames]
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to extract the signal/strength at those individual beat timestamps.. Is it the right way or is there a way i can validate if its correct?

Answer (score 0):

A single audio sample is not a good measure for "signal strength". A better choice would be the soundlevel, for example computed via [librosa.feature.rms](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.feature.rms.html). You can set a frame_length (in samples) to correspond for example 10 ms.